# How to pass &:key as an argument to map instead of a block with ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, rubocop

I wrote this code:

```
my.objects.map { |object| object.key }
```

My rubocop said:

```
Pass &:key as an argument to map instead of a block.
```

Is there a short way to do the same thing?

Comment: You can use `rubocop -a yourfile.rb` to let Rubocop auto-correct your code.

Comment: @cremno add this comment as an answer .. I search for this many times but now I found it (y) thank you

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Pass &:key as an argument to map instead of a block

means:

```
my.objects.map(&:key)
```

Comment: For people having any confusion, you can pass 'transformation function' like `to_i` or `to_s` instead of key. That is to say, it'll look something like below.
`my.objects.map(&:to_i)`